# How to calculate diff between two non consecutive rows in sql

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

[image]

I am trying to calculate the third column, as a result of diff between first row and second row, first row and third row and so on using sql. would anybody help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your table is sorted by **col1** with alphabetical order,

```sql
SELECT c1, c2, c2 - FIRST_VALUE(c2) OVER (ORDER BY c1) AS c3
 FROM `your_table`;
```

will output below result.

[image]

Comment: Bingo! got the desired output , Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the example you have provided where we have a unique value `a` that corresponds to the value `10` under `column2`, I believe we could do something like this for a solution:

```
SELECT
    a.column1,
    a.column2,
    (a.column2 - b.column2) AS column3
FROM table a
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT column2
    FROM table
    WHERE column1 = 'a'
) b
```

This will get you a way to hold the value for 10 statically inside of the outer apply, so it can be subtracted from each value that is passed in.